# User Supplied Initial States in Statespace Model

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am trying to replicate the result in Trends and Cycles in Macroeconomic Time Series (1985). I was able to get the same result if using only Local Linear models, but failed to do so when adding a stationary cyclical component. Although I am not entirely sure, I suspect it has to do with me using full diffuse priors for all states instead of on the local linear components only. To maintain some level of flexibility, I would like to feed initials to `statsmodels` using `known` keyword, and update them in the `update` method. For now I am not worry too much about using approximate diffuse. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v0.10, you can get quite a bit of flexibility in setting the initialization by creating your own `Initialization` instance. Using this approach, each state or block of states can be independently set to use one of the available methods: `known`, `stationary`, `approximate_diffuse` or `diffuse`.

Here is an example of a local level model, but where the irregular component is modeled as an AR(1). The first state is the AR(1), and I specify `stationary` initialization. The second state is the level, and I estimate the initial level via maximum likelihood, using the `known` initialization. The third state is the slope, and I set its initialization to `diffuse`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.initialization import Initialization
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.tools import (
    constrain_stationary_univariate,
    unconstrain_stationary_univariate)

class LocalLevelAR1(sm.tsa.statespace.MLEModel):
    def __init__(self, endog):
        super().__init__(endog, k_states=3, k_posdef=3)

        self['design', 0, :2] = 1
        self['transition', 1:, 1:] = np.array([[1., 1.],
                                               [0., 1.]])
        self['selection'] = np.eye(3)

        init = Initialization(3)
        init.set(0, 'stationary')
        init.set(1, 'known', stationary_cov=[[0]])
        init.set(2, 'diffuse')
        self.ssm.initialization = init

    @property
    def state_names(self):
        return ['ar1', 'level', 'slope']

    @property
    def param_names(self):
        return ['level0', 'phi', 'sigma2.ar1', 'sigma2.level', 'sigma2.slope']

    @property
    def start_params(self):
        return np.r_[0, 0, 1e-5, 1e-5, 1e-5]

    def transform_params(self, unconstrained):
        constrained = unconstrained.copy()
        constrained[1] = constrain_stationary_univariate(unconstrained[1:2])
        constrained[2:5] = constrained[2:5]**2
        return constrained

    def untransform_params(self, constrained):
        unconstrained = constrained.copy()
        unconstrained[1] = unconstrain_stationary_univariate(constrained[1:2])
        unconstrained[2:5] = constrained[2:5]**0.5
        return constrained

    def update(self, params, **kwargs):
        params = super().update(params, **kwargs)

        self['transition', 0, 0] = params[1]
        self['state_cov'] = np.diag(params[2:5])
        self.ssm.initialization.set(1, 'known', constant=params[:1], stationary_cov=[[0.]])

dta = sm.datasets.macrodata.load_pandas().data
dta.index = pd.period_range(start='1959Q1', end='2009Q3', freq='Q')

mod = LocalLevelAR1(dta['infl'])
res = mod.fit()

print(res.summary())
```

Comment: This is wonderful! Thanks for the great answer! This is a really great package.  I am trying to run your code and see the following warning `ConvergenceWarning: Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to converge. Check mle_retvals` . Is it normal? And I also noticed you didn't use likelihood_burn in initialisation, does the keyword `diffuse` automatically handles that?

Comment: Glad to hear you're finding it useful!

In this case, because my starting parameters were not good, it needs a few more iterations than the default to reach convergence at the specified tolerance. If you use: `res = mod.fit(maxiter=100)` then the message goes away.

Yes, when using `diffuse` you do not need to specify `loglikelihood_burn`, because it can compute the exact value directly.